# How to customize scrollbar in Material UI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, scrollbar

I am using Material-UI to expand my React project, but i can't change the scrollbars in the mui components.
This was the css i was using before mui integration:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #1a1b1c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid 2px #282c34;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #1a1b1c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid 2px #1a1b1c;
}
```

After using mui I realized css is overwritten by mui's own styling while using mui components such as `<Box/>` or `<Drawer/>`. I'm also using `<ThemeProvider/>` from mui with following theme:

```
export const dark_theme = createTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      mobile: 0,
      desktop: 1024,
    },
  },
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
    primary: {
      main: "#3f51b5",
      contrastText: "#fff",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#8700ff",
      contrastText: "#fff",
    },
    background: {
      default: "#282c34",
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "Poppins",
    allVariants: {
      color: "white",
    },
  },
  overrides: {},
});
```

After trying [CSS Baseline](https://mui.com/components/css-baseline/#scrollbars) overrides from mui documentation, i couldn't get any results but also couldn't confirm what was the problem due to my limited understanding of mui`s styling and the fact that [CSS Baseline scrollbars](https://mui.com/components/css-baseline/#scrollbars) was marked deprecated.

how can i integrate the above shown css scrollbar styles to a mui component or mui theme?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed the parent class and the webkit, like this (calendar component MUI)

```js
MuiCalendarPicker: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          '.css-1wvgxus-MuiCalendarPicker-viewTransitionContainer::-webkit-scrollbar': {
            width: '8px',
            marginRight: '5px'
          },
          '.css-1wvgxus-MuiCalendarPicker-viewTransitionContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
            background: '#E4E7EB', 
            borderRadius: '100px'
          },
          '.css-1wvgxus-MuiCalendarPicker-viewTransitionContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
            background: '#6B7786',
            borderRadius: '100px'
          },
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using MUI version 5 and for me adding `enableColorScheme` in `CssBaseline` worked. As suggested in [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/#color-scheme)

```
import React from 'react';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider, useMediaQuery, CssBaseline } from '@mui/material';
import Home from './components/home';

function App() {
  // Use the useMediaQuery hook to check if the user prefers dark mode
  const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

  // Create the theme based on the user's preference
  const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: prefersDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
    },
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline enableColorScheme/>
      <Home/>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```